# How to load different views for mobile and desktop for angular and bootstrap application for shopping cart application

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

We are using angular and bootstrap for shopping cart application. I need to route different pages for mobile and desktop screens. For example /cart route should open different page in mobile and different page in desktop view (based -md, -lg and -sm , -xs)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
path: '' ,
component: (() => {
  return SessionService.isDesktop() ? DesktopComponent : MobileComponent;
})()
} 
]
```

where you manage `isDesktop()` as a `boolean` function in a global service, and check for screen changes over there.

Comment: How SessionService.isDesktop() will return desktop or mobile. How it will check, Can you provide code snippet for this method.